# How to show the function function $f(a,b)=a+b\sqrt2$ from $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$ is bijection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

So I have this question that I've answered and don't know if it's correct:

Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is denumerable.

Proof:

We define a function $f$:$\mathbb{Q}$$\times$$\mathbb{Q}$$\to$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ by the formula $f(a,b)=a+b\sqrt{2}$. Since we know that $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ is countable hence denumerable, it's easy to check that $f$ is one-to-one and onto.

If the proof is correct how do you check that $f$ is actually a bijection??

Comment: You could also use Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem instead. The injective from one to the other in both cases is simple.

Comment: Btw, the title of your post is misleading. There is no multivalued function here.

Comment: Sorry about that, what's the name for such a function??

Comment: There's nothing special about this function. It's just a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Your approach is correct.

$f$ is injective, because if $f(a,b) = f(c,d)$, then $a-c = \sqrt{2}(d-b)$. Since $\sqrt{2} \notin\mathbb{Q}$, it follows that $d=b$, and hence $a=c$.

$f$ is surjective, because $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}$. Now the set
$$
\{a+b\sqrt{2} : a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}
$$
is another field (check this) that contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}$. Hence, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \subset f(\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but is there a proposition that shows that if the (smallest) proper subset of the co-domain of a function is the image of that function in a particular formula then that function is onto??

Comment: You don't need a proposition, they're showing you in the answer that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ is a *subset* of $f(\Bbb Q \times\Bbb Q)$. Meaning that every element of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ is "contained" within the image of $\Bbb Q \times\Bbb Q$. And f has to map a set *onto* its image by definition of image therefore f must be onto. Also what do you mean by "that function in a particular formula"? There were no formulas used here.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that even better than a bijection, this is an isomorphism if you define addition and multiplication on $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ the right way.